# jQuery isotope sort price

Tags: jquery, string, sorting, replace, jquery-isotope

I'm not having much luck in getting correct sorts with pricing as I belive the $ sign is interfering but I cannot get the replace function to work.

My HTML

```
<span class="field-content price">$486.15</span>
```

My jquery function

```
price : function( $elem ) {
        return parseFloat( $elem.find('.price').text().replace($, '') );
      }
```

For some reason this does not seem to be removing the $ sign. Am i missing something in the function?

Im also not sure if the decimal point could also be causing problems with the sort

Thanks in advance

Comment: try quotes around the $: .replace('$', '')

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NMvwb/)

enclose `$` in with in quotes `'$'`

```
price : function( $elem ) {
        return parseFloat( $elem.find('.price').text().replace('$', '') );
      }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NMvwb/2)

```
function x ($elem) {
    return parseFloat($elem.replace('$', ''));
}
$('.price').each(function(){
     $(this).text(x($(this).text()));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i tried the modification you suggested and it still does not work http://jsfiddle.net/NMvwb/1/

Comment: Your fiddle works great, however when i try put it into the rest of my function I'm getting errors, sorry if im missing something really simple here, thanks for your help so far, so close now! http://jsfiddle.net/A62LM/

Answer (score 0):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Vy9Cd/

You needed to enclose the $ in quotes:

```
      price: function x ($elem) {
          var price = parseFloat( $elem.find('.price').text().replace('$', '') );
          return price;
      }
```

However you also had a number of other issues:

- HTML not matching the expected HTML by javascript
- Javascript would not even compile
- Missing isotope library

I recommend starting with a simple example and familiarizing yourself with handling syntax errors so that you can at least start with a working example.